# How to register if a specific contact visits a page? And how to validate if they performed a certain action? Mautic

Tags: contacts, mautic

**First part of the question**

I’ve registered in Mautic a number X of contacts via API from my main website, all those contacts have basic info including their name and id (I do not have their IPs). Now, I will send all of them a SMS with a link to a landing page. I want to register exaclty which of those X contacts are visiting the page.
I have to mention that a campaign exist for tracking this process. So, when a contacts visits the page, some actions or validations will ocurr.

What should I do to make Mautic know which contacts from those X are visiting the page?

**My idea**

Send the URL with a specifc parameter that somewhat allows Mautic to understand which one of the contact visited.

Is this possible? Do you consider there is a another way?

**Second part**

I have a form with one field on the page that register a cellphone number. I wish to register which contact is registering the number.

How can this be achieved?

**My Idea:**

I am thinking of adding another field asking the contact id, so the contact has to fill that in order to send the form

Answer (score 1):

If you append the link sent via SMS with a `?email={contactfield=email|true}`, the Mautic tracking pixel (cookie) will pick up this email when the user lands on the page and collapse the anonymous tracking session into the identified tracking session.

I haven't tested if you can also do this with SMS numbers or with contact IDs.

We publish our best practices for this, here: https://facetinteractive.com/blog/the-ultimate-mautic-setup-guide#emails